# Find the maximum value from sublists with common element

Tags: max, nested-lists

I have a nested list:

```
input_list = [[12, 123182, 94], [12, 125201, 6], [13, 123180, 3], [13, 125272, 93], [13, 125987, 4]]
```

I need to find the sublist whose third element has the largest value depending on the common first element in a list, and return the first two elements in that sublist inside a new list.

Desired output:

```
output_list = [[12, 123182], [13, 125272]]
```

In the example above the common elements were 12 and 13 and the third element's largest values in those sublists were 94 and 93, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. All explanations are in the comments. I think it's pretty straight forward code - the only exception is the 'key' argument of max() function which is not very popular.

```
input_list = [[12, 123182, 94], [12, 125201, 6], [13, 123180, 3], [13, 125272, 93], [13, 125987, 4]]
# desired_output_list = [[12, 123182], [13, 125272]]

# get the all possible 1st values
keys = {i[0] for i in input_list}

# group data into dict of lists, with 1st value as a key
input_as_dict = dict()
for k in keys:
    input_as_dict[k] = [i for i in input_list if i[0] == k]

print(f'input_as_dict = {input_as_dict}')

output_list = []
for k, v in input_as_dict.items():
    # calculate max within each key
    m = max(v, key=lambda x: x[2])  # use 'key' argument to calculate maximum within list of lists based on 3rd element of a list
    print(f'max for key={k} is: {m}')
    output_list.append(m[:2])  # adding truncated (3rd element removed) list to final output

print(output_list)
```